# Generating Random Samples According to Gamma-Exponential Distribution

Tags: probability

Suppose that we have a multivariate Gamma-Exponential Distribution with pdf
$$
p(x,y) = \frac{{{\theta _1}^{{\theta _2}}{\theta _3}}}{{\Gamma ({\theta _2})}}{x^{{\theta _2}}}{e^{ - {\theta _1}x - {\theta _3}xy}}$$

How can I generate random samples according to this distribution?

Comment: @MahdiKhosravi Changing the size of the fonts is not desirable in general (and certainly not in the present case). Surely you can find more constructive ways to contribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you divide $p(x,y)$ by $\theta_3 x e^{-\theta _3x y}$, you would get $\frac{e^{-x \theta _1} x^{+\theta_2 - 1} \theta _1^{\theta _2}}{\Gamma\left(\theta _2\right)}$ which immediately shows that the marginal for $X$ is gamma with parameters $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ and that the conditional of $Y$ given $X=x$ is exponential with parameter $x\theta_3$.
To sample from $p(x,y)$, start by sampling $X$ from a gamma distribution with parameters $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ and then sample an exponential for $Y$ with parameter given the the sampled value of $X$ multiplied by $\theta_3$. Repeat that as many times as the required random sample is.